# Update Array of Objects with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am sending an array of object from a web page to C# via ajax. I am trying to update my table with the array of objects Please help.

This is the controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage Update([FromBody]List<Model> json)
{
    var result = db.Models.ToList();

    return response;
}
```

This is the Model class

```
    public int ID {get; set;}

    public string ModelNumber { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
```

Here is a sample of the json array

```
var json = [{ID:1,ModelNumber: gw234, Category: A, Partnumber: rty466m},{ID:2,ModelNumber: kw274, Category: B, Partnumber: tbg55},{ID:3,ModelNumber: gr456, Category: A, Partnumber: htg555}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming array of objects are type Entity(Model), you could set the entity state to modified

```
json.ForEach(m=> db.Entry(m).State = EntityState.Modified);

db.SaveChnages();
```

For more information check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: [Simply stating *try this* is a very poor answer.  Why does this answer work and where do I get more information about these methods I'm suppose to call?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

```
 using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;  

 public HttpResponseMessage Update([FromBody]List<Model> json)
    {
        var result = db.Models.ToList();

        // create object from dbContext
        var db = new MyDbContext();

        // add entities on dbContext,
        db.SomeRepo.AddOrUpdate(json); 
        // commit the change on db
        db.Save();  

        return response;
    }
```

**AddOrUpdate** method is in under   using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
if entity has id ,it will execute update else add

cheers

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below link.

[Updating Related Data with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)